# Regex para obtener texto que las contenga

Tags: java, regex, grails

tengo una duda con regex, me explico:
Estoy obteniendo datos de un JSONElement, el cual trae textos variados, por ejemplo:

```
1. J.C.A.577/2019/4/I Y ACUM.600/2019/4/V
2. CUAD.DE AMP.09/2021 J.C.A.671/2016/4/E
3. 70/2022/4a-III
4. 193/2020/4/E
5. 392/2020/3a-III
6. 647/2016/3a-I y Acumulado 648/2016
7. PRA/PRA/13/2020/3a-I
8. CUADERNO DE ANTECEDENTES 119/2021 RELATIVO AL JUICIO CONTENCIOSO 303/2021/2a-II
```

Y necesito que queden así:

```
1. 577/2019/4/I 600/2019/4/V
2. 09/2021 671/2016/4/E
3. 70/2022/4a-III
4. 193/2020/4/E
5. 392/2020/3a-III
6. 647/2016/3a-I 648/2016
7. 13/2020/3a-I
8. 119/2021 303/2021/2a-II
```

Para ello estoy usando las expresiones regulares, en mi caso es esta: `\d{1,}\/\d{4}` y me arroja lo siguiente:
[image: Imagen regex hecha en javaGOD]

Sin embargo, solo me obtiene los bloques de números y el primer slash.

Cuando la proceso en Java:

```
private def busquedaDelCaso(JSONElement amazonJSONArray, Date fecha){
  List listaCasos = casoBusquedaLocalService.findCasoBusquedaLocal()
  for(CasoBusqueda caso : listaCasos){
    for(JSONElement casoScraping : amazonJSONArray){
      def expedienteScraping = obtenerNumExpedientePorRegex(casoScraping.getAt("numeroExpediente"))
      def expedienteNormal = obtenerNumeroExpedientePorRegex(caso.noExpediente)
    }
  }
}

private def obtenerNumeroExpedientePorRegex(def obj){
  List matchList = new ArrayList()
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{1,}\\/\\d{4}")
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(obj.toString())
  for (int i = 0; matcher.find(); i++) {
    matchList.add(matcher.group())
  }
  return matchList
}
```

A la hora de pasa el debugger me arroja estos datos, los cuales no logro comprender ¿Alguna idea de lo que esta pasando?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que la regex que necesitas es `"\\d{1,}/\\d{4}[A-Za-z0-9/-]*"`. Observa que el carácter `/` no necesita escaparse (no lleva  \\ delante). Además extendí la expresión para que capture también el resto de la "fecha" (barras adicionales seguidas de letras o números), tal como aparece en la salida deseada de tu ejemplo.

Comment: Estoy probando en la pagina regex101 con los datos que tengo y me dice que `Your regular expression does not match the subject string`

Comment: Prueba `\d+(\/[\w-]+)+`. La de que te sugirió abulafia también funciona, lo que te la escribió directamente en la sintaxis que debes escribirla en java, por eso en la página no funciona.

Comment: Otra pregunta, en caso de que en el texto no tenga un tercer / es decir, solo sea `23/3123` en este caso la regex tambien valida o ahi no lo acepta?

Comment: En ese caso el regex lo acepta también, no especificaste nunca el mínimo de `/` que necesitabas. De hecho, ese formato coincide con lo que quieres en la salida (como se muestra en tu línea 2). Checa la salida de un pequeño demo que hice con la expresión regular que te puse https://onlinegdb.com/xaVTTH6KE

Comment: Muchas gracias c: Me ha quedado claro el asunto  ¿Puedes crear la respuesta para aceptar y que la pregunta quede contestada? c:

Comment: @EdgarGc una pregunta que me llamó la atención de tu código. ¿Qué es `def` en `java`?  Primera vez que lo veo y lo tienes como tipo de retorno de tu método. Nunca lo habíá visto, aunque tengo la sospecha que en realidad es cosa Kotlin.

Comment: `def` es una palabra reservada de Groovy. Lo que pasa es que estoy trabajando con Grails, un framework de Groovy el cual tambien tambien acepta la sintaxis de Java. Puedes mezclarla y la JVM no tiene problema compilarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según la salida que adjuntas necesitas un `regex` que haga match con una cadena que empiece por **un número de uno o más dígitos**, y tenga después una o más combinaciones de **un `/` con una cadena de números, dígitos o `-`**.

Podrías usar `\d+(\/[\w-]+)+` donde `\d+` representa 1 o más dígitos y `(\/[\w-]+)+` una combinación de un `/` seguida por una cadena de números, dígitos o `-`.

Te adjunto un pequeño demo en Java que puedes ejecutar [acá](https://onlinegdb.com/I4HObux6V):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String string = "1. J.C.A.577/2019/4/I Y ACUM.600/2019/4/V\n" +
                "2. CUAD.DE AMP.09/2021 J.C.A.671/2016/4/E\n" +
                "3. 70/2022/4a-III\n" +
                "4. 193/2020/4/E\n" +
                "5. 392/2020/3a-III\n" +
                "6. 647/2016/3a-I y Acumulado 648/2016\n" +
                "7. PRA/PRA/13/2020/3a-I\n" +
                "8. CUADERNO DE ANTECEDENTES 119/2021 RELATIVO AL JUICIO CONTENCIOSO 303/2021/2a-II";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+(\\/[\\w-]+)+");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(string);
        
        int count = 1;
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
            System.out.print(count + ". ");
        
            while (matcher.find()) {
                System.out.print(matcher.group() + " ");
            }
            System.out.println  ();
        
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Este programa tiene como salida:

```
1. 577/2019/4/I 600/2019/4/V 
2. 09/2021 671/2016/4/E 
3. 70/2022/4a-III 
4. 193/2020/4/E 
5. 392/2020/3a-III 
6. 647/2016/3a-I 648/2016 
7. 13/2020/3a-I 
8. 119/2021 303/2021/2a-II
```